# How to handle long processing jobs in .Net core and with any suitable azure resource?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I am working in application and it has few components like single page application, back-end API application written in .Net core. My back-end application calls azure function which will run for 2 to 10 mins depending on the data processing. So I do not want to wait for the Azure function to complete the processing. so after googling around for quite some time I came up with below approach.

I will place one service bus/queue between my back end and azure function. As soon as UI triggers something my back-end API will be called and add some messages to queue/service bus. I will add some trigger to my azure function to start of when message is added to service bus/ queue. Once message comes to queue/ service bus azure function executes lets say around 5 mins and it will call again one more azure function and here in my last azure function I have added implementation for SignalR to push notification to UI.

This is what I thought this solution to handle long processing jobs. All my webapps/api app deployed to azure app service. Now my only question is this is appropriate solution or some better way I can handle this? Can someone help me this is best solution or any better work around will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a service bus you might consider creating a worker process handles the 2-to-10-minute processing loads.  You have lots of choices for writing that sort of app and running it in Azure, including console applications or a function app. You can also host long playing services in your web app, the trade-off is between more complicated code (co-hosting web and long playing app) and deploying an extra app.